# CSS Overlaying Images on a Specific Screen Size

Tags: html, css

So I want to overlay some images on top of one another, but only when viewing the website on an iPad / iPhone.

I have wrote the following code which works as it should by itself. However, when the @media function is added, nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<section class="logos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="img1"><img src="./images/testing1.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="img2"><img src="./images/testing2.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="img3"><img src="./images/testing3.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="img4"><img src="./images/testing4.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="img5"><img src="./images/testing5.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
.container{
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0; }

.img1{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0; }

.img2{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0; }

.img3{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0; }

.img4{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0; }

.img5{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0; }
}
```

Comment: This is working as is: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a width and a height to your container if you wish for this to work as there is currently nothing so the image is absolute but to what as the container has no height set. so my sugesstion is to find out the current height that is fine for your images, eg,

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {

    .container {
      position: relative;
      background:#000;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      clear:both;
      display: inline-block;
        }

    .img1{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; }

    .img2{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; }

    .img3{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; }

    .img4{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; }

    .img5{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; }
    }
```

Another solution would be the below

```
    .logos .container {
      position: relative; }

    .logos .container img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {

    .img2{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; }

    .img3{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; }

    .img4{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; }

    .img5{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; }
    }
```

How the above works is by leaving the first image as static. so the container has something still in it.

PS. the backgorund #000 is just so you can see what is going on. remove this,